# Extending Material UI's existing dark mode colors

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, extending, darkmode

Material UI's default theme ships a palette of colors, including a special set of **dark colors** ([docs](https://next.material-ui.com/customization/palette/#dark-mode), [code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.0-beta.4/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js)).

What makes these dark mode colors special is components who consume them don't need to depend on knowing the theme's `palette.mode` (aka light/dark mode) - they update automatically.
[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-dark-light-kt6vf)

My goal is to *extend* this set of colors, such that components I write can use **new** colors beyond this built-in set, e.g. `theme.palette.myColor` and benefit from the same automatic behavior.

In other words, I don't want to have dark mode logic be duplicated in each theme-consuming component:

```js
const WhatIDontWantComponent = () => (
  <Box
    sx={{
      color: (theme) =>
        theme.palette.mode === "light"
          ? theme.palette.myColor.light
          : theme.palette.myColor.dark,
    }}
  />
);
```

I instead want to use

```js
const WhatIWantComponent = () => (
  <Box
    sx={{
      color: (theme) => theme.palette.myColor
    }}
  />
);
```

So `myColor` would be included in the light/dark set that already exists, and benefit from this automatic behavior.

[image: Example]

Possible? Is there some way to accomplish this within my app without patching MUI in some way to accept custom colors?

---

deps

- @material-ui/core version 5.0.0-beta.4
- react, react-dom 17.0.2
- next.js 11.0

Answer (score 4):

Ended up going with this:

```js
const baseTheme = createTheme({...common options...})
export const lightTheme = createTheme({ ...light specific...}, baseTheme)
export const darkTheme = createTheme({ mode: "dark", ...dark specific...}, baseTheme)
```

based on [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21757#issuecomment-657226028) discussion.
We basically perform theme composition in multiple steps + utilizing how the second arg to `createTheme()` gets deepmerge'd.

Once you have the two themes, you could consider setting up a toggle by bringing your own `mode`:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={mode ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
  {...app...}
</ThemeProvider>
```

This works, but IMO a downside of this approach though is that I have two themes and have to manage dark/light state externally. Not a huge problem but feels a bit redundant -- in my mind dark/light mode seems like a concern that could (should) be handled internally to a single theme.

Perhaps there are good reasons against, but IMO it feels more ergonomic if MUI would allow users to specify our own dark palette, like I asked in my original question, vs the current [hard coded one](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.0-beta.4/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js#L52).

So if you're looking for custom MUI dark colors, this approach seems to be the best one given the situation right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the material-ui theme using [theme provider](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#theme-provider) component in order to add your custom colors for e.g,

```
  import { createTheme, colors } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

  const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: "#F6F7FF",
      paper: colors.common.white
    },
    primary: {
      main: "#43A047"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#43A047"
    },
    text: {
      primary: "#000000",
      secondary: "#6b778c"
    },
    // Add your custom colors if any
  },
});
```

You can write this configuration code inside a separate file and then import it into your root component file.

```
import theme from "src/theme";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";


<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <YourRootComponent />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Then consume it the same way you do it for the default material UI colors

Also, you can customize typography, shadows, override default class, and much more [check out this](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#theme-configuration-variables)

Comment: Thanks for your response Asad.

You may not have seen the code sandbox I included, I'm already using the `ThemeProvider`. The problem with adding custom colors in the way you've described is that these are not included in the set the built-in dark mode toggles. Instead it looks like I need to custom colors to this object: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.0-beta.4/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js#L52

Comment: `<ThemeProvider>` is used at bottom of this file https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-dark-light-kt6vf?file=/app.tsx

Comment: Oh, my bad. Have you tried this https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18831#issuecomment-565753962 ?

Comment: As per now, I don't think there is any support for that, the ideal solution would be that one can define two variation of custom color respective to the mode.